# Writing RDD Data to CSV with Dynamic Columns in Spark - Scala

Tags: scala, csv, hadoop, apache-spark

I am reading multiple files from an HDFS directory, and for each file the generated data is printed using:

```
frequencies.foreach(x => println(x._1 + ": "+x._2))
```

And the printed data is (for *File1.txt*):

```
'text': 45
'data': 100
'push': 150
```

The key can be different for other files like (*File2.txt*):

```
'data': 45
'lea': 100
'jmp': 150
```

The key is not necessarily the same in all the files. I want all the file data to be written to a .csv file in the following format:

```
Filename   text  data  push  lea  jmp
File1.txt  45    100   150   0    0
File2.txt  0     45    0     100  150  ....
```

Can someone please help me find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest creating one dataframe for all the files inside your directory and then using a `pivot` to re-shape the data accordingly :

```
val df1 = sc.parallelize(Array(
("text",45  ),
("data",100 ),
("push",150 ))).toDF("key", "value").withColumn("Filename", lit("File1") )

val df2 = sc.parallelize(Array(
("data",45  ),
("lea",100 ),
("jump",150 ))).toDF("key", "value").withColumn("Filename", lit("File2") )

val df = df1.unionAll(df2)

df.show
+----+-----+--------+
| key|value|Filename|
+----+-----+--------+
|text|   45|   File1|
|data|  100|   File1|
|push|  150|   File1|
|data|   45|   File2|
| lea|  100|   File2|
|jump|  150|   File2|
+----+-----+--------+


val finalDf = df.groupBy($"Filename").pivot("key").agg(first($"value") ).na.fill(0)

finalDf.show
+--------+----+----+---+----+----+
|Filename|data|jump|lea|push|text|
+--------+----+----+---+----+----+
|   File1| 100|   0|  0| 150|  45|
|   File2|  45| 150|100|   0|   0|
+--------+----+----+---+----+----+
```

You can write it as a CSV using `DataFrameWriter`

```
df.write.csv(..)
```

The hard part with this would be creating a different dataframe for each file with an extra column for the `Filename` from which the dataframe is created

Comment: I am not able to write the `finalDf` to csv using df.write.csv and getting this error: `value csv is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter` . Thanks @philantrovert

Comment: If you're using Spark 1.6, you'll need to add the databricks csv jar to your application. And the code will change to `df.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")`. More info here : https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv

Comment: Sorry but i've searched alot about it and didn't find a way to make jar file from this github repo and how to add it in application. It would be great help if u mention these steps here please.. Thanks @philatrovert

Comment: I've figured it out.. Thanks @philantrovert

Comment: When i am running this code on 11,00 files (Dataset text files), i am getting an error `java.lang.StackOverFlowError`. I am calling a function for each file and the Union action is performed with the previous dataframes and this will continue for each file. Would you please suggest what should be done to avoid this error with no decrease in time?

Answer (score 1):

If your files doesn't big enough, you can done without spark.
Here is my example code, csv format is old style, doesn't like your expected output, but you can tweak it easily.

```
  import scala.io.Source
  import org.apache.hadoop.fs._
  val sparkSession =   ...  // I created it to retrieve hadoop configuration, you can create your own Configuration.
  val inputPath =   ...
  val outputPath =   ...

  val fs = FileSystem.get(sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
  // read all files content to Array of Map[String,String]
  val filesContent = fs.listStatus(new Path(inputPath)).filter(_.isFile).map(_.getPath).filter(_.getName.endsWith(".txt"))
    .map(s => (s.getName, Source.fromInputStream(fs.open(s)).getLines()
                    .map(_.split(":").map(_.trim))
                    .filter(_.length == 2)
                    .map(p => (p.head, p.last)).toMap))
  // create default Map with all possible keys
  val listKeys = filesContent.flatMap(_._2.keys).distinct.map(s => (s, "0")).toMap
  val csvContent = filesContent.map(s => (s._1, listKeys ++ s._2))
    .map(s => (s._1, s._2.values.mkString(",")))
    .map(s => s"${s._1},${s._2}")
    .mkString("\n")
  val csvHeader = ("Filename" +: listKeys.keys.toList).mkString(",")
  val csv = csvHeader + "\n" + csvContent

  new PrintWriter(fs.create(new Path(outputPath))){
    write(csv)
    close()
  }
```